# tinytable how to sort table in descending order rather then ascending

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm using the tinytable table sorting script.

See example at http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/table-sorter/index.html.

It's a very basic script about 2.5kb. To use the script we do `sorter.init("table",1);` where table is the table id and 1 is the initial column to be sorted. This works great but initial column is sorted in asc order. There is not an option to make it initially sort in descending order. I tried to look into the js file but couldn't figure it out. What do I need to do to make it the initial column sort in desc order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line of the script reads `return g>h?1:(g<h?-1:0)`.

Change it to `return g<h?1:(g>h?-1:0)` and you should be done.

**Edit:**

If you click on the `Name` cell of the intial column, it also sort in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on this and to sort the table in a descending order just change the sort direction to be -1

```js
    sortcolumn:0, // sort column 1
    sortdir:-1, // sort direction either 1 asc or -1 desc
```